# Cannot Find Symbol - method error

Tags: java, methods

I have a problem in this code.
I have clearly written the method show() in the Bag class.
But why is the compiler showing cannot find symbol for the method when I try to access the show method in the main()?

```
public class Bag1<Item> 
{
private int N;
private Node<Item> first;

public Bag1()
{
    N = 0;
    first = null;
}

private class Node<Item>
{
    private Item item;
    private Node<Item> next;
}

public void add(Item item)
{
    Node<Item> oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node<Item>();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    N++;
}

public int size() 
{
    return N;
}

public void show()  
{
    Node<Item> oldfirst = first;
    while(first.next!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(first.item + " ");
        first = first.next;
    }
}       
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Bag<String> bag = new Bag<String>();
    while(s.hasNext())
    {   
        String item = s.next();
        if(!item.equals("-"))
            bag.add(item);
        else
            break;
    }
    bag.show();
    System.out.println("Size of the bag: " +bag.size());

}
}
```

Comment: what exactly is it that it can't find?

Comment: Bag1 class has the show() method not Bag

Comment: `show` method is in class `Bag1` as shown in your code not in `Bag`

Answer (score 0):

Your `bag` object is of type `Bag<String>`  but your `show` method is on a `Bag1` object

Answer (score 0):

In main() method change second line like this,may be it should works for you,
 Bag1 bag = new Bag1();

While compiling java application ,java compiler checks that Bag1 class contains show() method or not,if method is not available java compiler throws "cannot find symbol": show().

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access **show()** method with `Bag` class object, that does not exist in your class, it should be `Bag1`

```
 Bag1<String> bag1=new Bag1<String>();
 bag1.show();
```